# I have Error in the spring jdbc run application

Tags: java

I run spring jdbc project but have some Errors: i attach main method test code

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
public Test() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException{
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String salary = req.getParameter("salary");

    int result = Integer.parseInt(id);
    float sala = Float.parseFloat(salary);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    Employee emp = (Employee) ctx.getBean("Employee");
    emp.setId(result);
    emp.setName(name);
    emp.setSalary(sala);

    EmployeeDao edao = (EmployeeDao) ctx.getBean("EmployeeDao");

    int status = edao.saveEmployee(emp);
    if (status > 0) {
        out.print("<p>Record saved successfully!</p>");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").include(req, resp);
    } else {
        out.print("Sorry! unable to save record!");
    }

    out.close();
}
```

}

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.log4j.net.JMSSink
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener

Comment: Looks like your code is servlet code. You need a server like tomcat to run it.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError generally comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time.

org.apache.log4j.net.JMSSink class internally implements interface javax.jms.MessageListener. But in your case seems jar containing MessageListerer is not present in your classpath.

Add javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar to your classpath and then try.